# Numpy n-tuple array with dtype float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, tuples

I need an expression that will grant me an 8-tuple `float` array. Currently, I have the 8-tuple array via:

```
E = np.zeros((n,m), dtype='8i') #8-tuple
```

However, when I append an indices `i,j` via:

```
E[i,j][0] = 1000.2 #etc.
```

I get back a tuple array with dtype `int`:

```
[1000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
```

It appears I need a way of using the `dtype` within my `zeros` command to both set the n-tuple and the `float` value.  Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: Am I missing something? Why not just do `E = np.zeros((n, m, 8), dtype=float)`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell that actually produces a much cleaner output in my window!  The data appears the same; is there any difference?

Comment: I don't think so but then I've never used it the way you do. Where did you find the `dtype='8i'` syntax? I can't find it in the `numpy` documentation, I suspect it's a legacy thing.

Comment: What's the `E.shape` and `E.dtype`?  Is it a 3d array, or 2d with compound dtype?

Comment: In Python a tuple is marked with `()`, not `[]`. `numpy` uses a list like notation except when display elements of a `structured` array.  Do you want a 3d array or a 2d structured array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an array is integer `dtype`, then assigned values will be truncated:

```
In [169]: x=np.array([0,1,2])
In [170]: x
Out[170]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [173]: x[0] = 1.234
In [174]: x
Out[174]: array([1, 1, 2])
```

The array has to have a float dtype to hold float values.

Simply changing the `i` (integer) to `f` (float) produces a float array:

```
In [166]: E = np.zeros((2,3), dtype='8f')
In [167]: E.shape
Out[167]: (2, 3, 8)
In [168]: E.dtype
Out[168]: dtype('float32')
```

This '8f' dtype is not common.  The string actually translates to:

```
In [175]: np.dtype('8f')
Out[175]: dtype(('<f4', (8,)))
```

But when used in `np.zeros` that `8` is treated as a dimension.  Usually we specify all dimensions in the shape, as @FHTMitchell notes:

```
In [176]: E1 = np.zeros((2,3,8), dtype=np.float32)
In [177]: E1.shape
Out[177]: (2, 3, 8)
In [178]: E1.dtype
Out[178]: dtype('float32')
```

---

Your use of 'n-tuple' is unclear.  While `shape` is a tuple, numeric arrays don't use tuple notation.  That is reserved for structured arrays.

```
In [180]: np.zeros((3,), dtype='f,f,f,f')
Out[180]: 
array([(0., 0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0., 0.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4')])
In [181]: _.shape
Out[181]: (3,)
```

This is a 1d array with 3 elements.  The `dtype` shows 4 fields.  Each element, or record, is displayed as a tuple.

But fields are indexed by name, not number:

```
In [182]: Out[180]['f1']
Out[182]: array([0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

It is also possible to put 'arrays' within fields:

```
In [183]: np.zeros((3,), dtype=[('f0','f',(4,))])
Out[183]: 
array([([0., 0., 0., 0.],), ([0., 0., 0., 0.],), ([0., 0., 0., 0.],)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4', (4,))])
In [184]: _['f0']
Out[184]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Initially I thought the `8f` notation would produce this sort of array.  But apparently I have to either use the full notation with field name, or make a comma separated string:

```
In [185]: np.zeros((3,), dtype='4f,i')
Out[185]: 
array([([0., 0., 0., 0.], 0), ([0., 0., 0., 0.], 0),
       ([0., 0., 0., 0.], 0)], dtype=[('f0', '<f4', (4,)), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

`dtype` notation can be confusing, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

---

Unless you are intentionally trying to create a structured array, it is best to stay away from the '8f' notation.

```
In [189]: np.array([0,1,2,3],dtype='4i')
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

In [190]: np.array([[0,1,2,3]],dtype='4i')
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

In [191]: np.array([(0,1,2,3)],dtype='4i')     # requires [(...)]
Out[191]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

Without the 4, I can simply write:

```
In [193]: np.array([[0,1,2,3]], dtype='i')
Out[193]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=int32)
In [194]: np.array([0,1,2,3], dtype='i')
Out[194]: array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [195]: np.array([[0,1,2,3]])
Out[195]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Whoa, amazing description here.  Thanks a ton @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

E = np.zeros((n,m), dtype='8**f**')

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`E = np.zeros((n,m), dtype='8f') #8-tuple`

Comment: consider adding an explanation to your code, and why is it better/different than the OPs' code. Also show output if possible.